# Is there any application that roots all android devices??

Tags: rooting

i have a requirement that needs a device to be rooted , but i have 4-5 different branded devices and i would definitely want them to be rooted by the same application for simplicity purpose.Please suggest an app that roots all devices to root.

Comment: Different devices can have widely varying root methods. The problem runs deep depending on security measures implemented by the manufacturers, software/kernel versions, and even hardware. I'm fairly certain there is no silver bullet that roots every device.

Answer (score 2):

Such an application does not exist.

Rooting an Android device is a complex process that involves two major steps: bypass the securtiy and anti-rooting measures of the device, and install the su command and app. This first step is the major roadblock in rooting a device.

To bypass the security that is put in place by both the Android system and the device manufacturer to discourage rooting. The method for doing this varies wildly by the device in question, the version of Android installed, and software such as a bootloader lock or "security" app installed by the device vendor or the carrier. This variety is why certain devices are yet to be rooted and why some must be wiped before rooting, etc. Though software exists to root a handful of devices by the same manufacturer (ex: Wug's Nexus Root Toolkit which can root the extremely similar Nexus S, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4, Nexus 7, and Nexus 10), this is only because the devices happen to use identical or extremely similar exploits to enable root. A single app cannot/need not be robust enough to handle every device by every manufacturer.

Comment: _That_ is an excellent answer.